# How to execute commands in CMD using python?

Tags: python, cmd, automation, scripting, command

I want to automate cmd commands using python but I also want the commands to show in CMD like I wrote them manually after launching the script. So for example, I want to use dir command in cmd, I tried doing that using subprocess module and the command executes properly but I also need the command to show like I wrote it myself before executing. I dont want the command to only execute and show the results. For example after launching the python script I want it to look like that:

> C:\Users\User\Bob>dir

And after that, the output of the command would show below. How do I do that?

My code that I used to execute dir command in cmd:

```
import subprocess, os
list_files = subprocess.run('dir', shell=True)
os.system("pause")
```

It executes the command just fine but I need the command as well.

Comment: Can you show your code ?

Comment: Added sample code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice library called [invoke](https://www.pyinvoke.org/) which can help you to automate shell commands with python. I've used it a couple times to do exactly that. You can install it via `python -m pip install invoke`. To make it output the shell command itself as well as it's output you could use it like this:

```py
from invoke import run
result = run("echo hello", hide=False, echo=True)
```

output would be

```sh
echo hi
hi
```

Have a look at the documentation for the *runners* [here](http://docs.pyinvoke.org/en/stable/api/runners.html).